# How to get list of libraries that are not up-to-date defined with Ivy

Tags: ant, ivy

We are using Ivy for managing dependencies in a big project.
There are 100+ libs defined in ivy.xml.

How can we get/check list of libs that are not up-to-date? (maybe 3rd party scripts/tasks)

Comment: First of all you need to use the ivy report task to get a clearer picture of your dependencies. Then you can change all the revision numbers to "latest.release" and ivy will go out and download the up to date jars. Compare the before and after

Comment: Thanks Mark but it's manual checking/editing/comparing.
I'm asking about automatic script/task that returns something like this:  
---
Current Version | Latest Version  |   Status  
guava-11.0.jar    guava-13.0.jar AVAILABLE UPDATE

Comment: Understood. No really safe way to auto update dependencies. For example your code could be using deprecated APIs that have been removed from the latest revision of your jars. It's a tough one which is why I suggested revising your build to use the "latest.release" dynamic revisions. At least going forwards you latest build will pull the latest code and you can spot problems, obviously at the risk of breaking your build.